# Condition NOT IN for subentity value

Tags: sql, mysql

I'am trying to add to my request on my entity 'worker' that contains worker.id, worker.name.. and a collection of entity worker.inadequatClients

a condition where it does not retrieve the worker at all if the argument $clientId is present in one of the inadequatClients worker collection, but it still retrieves it to me,
I figured i tried with leftJoin and NOT IN conditon.

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('w');
    $query->distinct()
        ->select('w.id, w.firstName, w.lastName, w.brigade, w.pushToken, w.sexe')
        ->leftJoin('w.inadequatClients', 'inaClients')
        ->addGroupBy('inaClients')
        ->andWhere(
                $query->expr()->notIn(':clientId', '(inaClients)')
        )
        ->addSelect('inaClients.clientId')
        ->setParameter('clientId', $clientId)
        ->leftJoin('w.meansOfTransport', 'meansOfTransport')
        ->addSelect('meansOfTransport.name as meansOfTransportName')
        ->leftJoin('w.squads', 's')
        ->addSelect('s.name as squadName')
        ->addSelect(
                    '(  SELECT COUNT(off.id) FROM \App\Entity\TemporateWorker AS temporateWorker 
                        LEFT JOIN temporateWorker.offerTemporateWorkers as off 
                        WHERE off.responseStatus = 3 AND temporateWorker.id = w.id 
                    ) as nbrOffer'
                );
    dd($query->getQuery()->getResult());
```

This still outputs a worker that contains a inadequatClients with the $clientId.